# Php Connecting to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

So I am trying to connect to a MySQL database through PHP.  The page is getting form input from an HTML page.

What the program below should do is check if the variable `$uName` is in my table named UserAccounts.  Here is the SQL expression

```
SELECT * FROM UserAccounts WHERE UserName= '$uName'"
```

I have tried it with and without the single quotes around uName. Then the code should echo the variable $name. The `$name` variable should be equal to the column Password2 in my table. Once the SQL works I intend to push this code into an if statement that checks whether or not the account exists. Then the code should redirect to the user homepage.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Also, if you are wondering what the `userLogin` and `userPass` variables are, they come from the form. They are the name of the two tags in my HTML form. The password value will eventually be included in the SQL as well.

```
<?php

  echo("<html><head><title>User Sign-Up</title></head>\n");

  $dbcnx = mysqli_connect("dbv","uName","pass", "db");
  // Check connection
  if (!$dbcnx) {
    echo( "<P>Unable to connect to the " .
    "database server at this time.</P>\n" );
    exit();
  }
  // Escape user inputs for security
  $uName = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcnx, $_REQUEST['userLogin']);
  $uPass = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcnx, $_REQUEST['userPass']);
  echo($uName);
  $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserAccounts WHERE UserName= '$uName'");
  $r = mysql_fetch_array($q);
  $name = $r['Password2'];
  echo($name);

?>
```

Comment: u are mixing both mysql_ and mysqli_ database extension..Use mysqli_

Comment: is the value displayed in  `echo($uName);` ?